# Auto Color assignment for my indicator script

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I wrote my pinescript indicator  and added it multiple times with different input values in the same chart, but I have to manually change to different color for easy identification.  Can the color be auto assign?  Just like I adding the standard indicator MA to the chart to the color will be automatically assigned with different ones

Thanks
RL

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible on custom indicator.
Tested so far:

1. Open one of the built-in script in the editor
2. Add to chart multiple times
3. You will see the plots are all in same color

Based on this, I can conclude that the auto color assignment is not handled via pinescript. Perhaps, this is an internal feature that's handled by tradingview engine and it only exclusively works on built-in indicators

Comment: thanks, now i had to add more 'complex' logic to determine the color by the input parameter (i.e. symbol)